# How do you show all rows with missing fields in Crystal Reports?

Tags: syntax, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm struggling with Crystal Reports suppressing rows whenever I add a field that some rows may not have data in.

I've been able to fix some of the rows and make them show by using the formula:

```
if not isnull({field}) then {field} else "Arbitrary string to make row display"
```

This at least fills in the absent field with something and displays the row.

Do I really have to try and identify *every* field that may have incomplete data for some rows? Or is there some global method to make all rows show no matter what?

Something like: `If isnull(ANYTHING) then " "`?

Comment: If you are adding individual fields then supress need to applied to individual fields....if you can post the image then we can think of any possible solution

Answer (score 2):

you can do right click on the field, then under suppress, click the formula icon beside it and you can input there the conditions.

Comment: I think you have to do this on every field.  You can do this by right click on field > Suppress(beside a checkbox) , across it has formula icon.

Comment: @ShemSeger if answer solves your issue then you can accept it as answer....how come adding more detail comes in to the picture

Comment: @siva The given solutions may be useful for someone else, but unfortunately for me they haven't solved my issue... I have given up votes though.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following in report options:

```
Convert Database NULL values to Default
Convert Other NULL values to Default.
```

This is hidden in File > Report Options.  I have used Convert Database NULL Values to default to show 0's instead of blanks for null valued summaries

Comment: I got exited about this one, but as soon as I checked these options Crystal got angry and told me a bunch of my formulas were suddenly wrong...